# Replace spaces with hyphen in query string in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i need that when i type a url like this: http://www.example.com/Fountain%20Hills-condos-townhouses then %20 or space is replaced by hyphen.
My htacces is:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*)-condos-townhouses$ index.php?cond_option=and&page=1&nextprev=0&searchBtn=0&displaylim=30&search_by=$1&search_cat_type=city&keyword=City&propType=2&listing_types=2&sortby=&searchpost=1&popup_in_seconds=1&is_popup_show=1&last_neighborhood=20&last_school=50&last_zips=20
```

I should get value of $_REQUEST['search_by'] is Fountain-Hills

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this right below `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)(?:\ |%20)(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1-%2 [L,R]
```

Comment: hi @jon Lin.., i have url like http://siteurl.com/search_results.asp?s=st%20christophers%20chain  
and http://siteurl.com/search_results.asp?s=st%20christophers
Its have multiple space(%20) in the url, how to manage this ..?
Help me..